# Connect MQTT with active/standby failover string

Tags: mqtt

I am trying to implement MQTT with failover string but unable to do so. I am using active/standby Amazon MQ broker. Here I have the faiolver string:
failover:(mqtt+ssl://b-e788a351-ba0b-382f-85f4-8b54bdb4e405-1.mq.us-east.amazonaws.com:8883,mqtt+ssl://b-e788a351-ba0b-382f-85f4-8b54bdb4e405-2.mq.us-east.amazonaws.com:8883)

Do anyone knows how to implement above in nodejs with mqtt module?

If it is single instance type broker then it is done using

const client = mqtt.connect("mqtts://example.com", mqttoptions);
But I am not sure how to implement with failover string. Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried this mqttoptions but it didn't work with mqtt.connect as we need to pass 1 argument in connect as String i.e HOST

```
 var mqttoptions = {
      clientId: username,
      port: 8883,
      keepalive: 60,
      username,
      password,
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      servers:[
      {
            protocol: 'mqtts',
            host: 'address-1',
            port: 8883
        },
        {
            protocol: 'mqtts',
            host: 'address-2',
            port: 8883
        }
     ]
  }

    const client = mqtt.connect(host, mqttoptions);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you check the doc for the `connect()` you will see that the first argument is optional.

> **mqtt.connect([url], options)**
>
> Connects to the broker specified by the given url and options and
> returns a Client.
>
> The URL can be on the following protocols: 'mqtt', 'mqtts', 'tcp',
> 'tls', 'ws', 'wss', 'wxs', 'alis'. The URL can also be an object as
> returned by URL.parse(), in that case the two objects are merged, i.e.
> you can pass a single object with both the URL and the connect
> options.
>
> You can also specify a servers options with content: [{ host:
> 'localhost', port: 1883 }, ... ], in that case that array is iterated
> at every connect.

The important bit is:

> in that case the two objects are merged, i.e. you can pass a single object with both the URL and the connect options.

This means you can just pass an options object that includes a `servers` options.